# uboot using FIT to upgrade

Tags: u-boot

I am using a custom embedded rtos and booting with uboot via a FIT image. "bootm" works very nicely with this .itb container.

I would like to include in the Sha signed image .itb file upgrades to my filesystem. That way uboot (via scripts) can upgrade files in the flash fat filesystem. The docs file update_uboot.its gives a hint as to what I need with:

```
    update@1 {
        description = "U-Boot binary";
        data = /incbin/("./u-boot.bin");
        compression = "none";
        type = "firmware";
        load = <FFFC0000>;
        hash@1 {
            algo = "sha1";
        };
    };
```

Where presumably this is a packaged binary upgrade for u-boot. And I can generate the image file with mkimage. However I cannot find any directions of how to use this or flash this, etc.

And generically there are several very interesting FIT types like "filesystem" which imply there is a way to package up a complete filesystem. That is very close to what I want, but I cannot find any way to extract and flash the filesystem from u-boot scripts.

I tried to do a "cp $loadaddr:update@1 0x90000000 10" but cp does not copy the data from the itb file. And from the source it looks like do_mem_cp does not do any special FIT syntax handling.

I am using a fairly recent TI Sitara uboot (u-boot-2016.05+gitAUTOINC+2f757e5b2c-g2f757e5b2c), do I need to modify the source to do what I want?

Thanks, Steve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the imxtract command to extract parts of a FIT image in memory.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for.  Google was not very helpful in finding examples but playing with it makes it clearer. How do I prepare a "filesystem" image type? Then does it get written directly to a flash partition because it contains directory info etc, or is it a collection of files that can be written separately? Maybe this is too much for a follow up, would you prefer another question topic?

Comment: The general answer is that it depends on how you have designed your upgrade mechanism (since this sounds home-grown rather than one of the existing mechanism like OSTree or resin.io).  The "easy" case here is that you have things designed such that you just replace the filesystem partition directly.